# Convert tiff to jpeg in node.js and GraphicsMagick

Tags: node.js, gm

How could I convert a `tiff` to `jpg` in node.js and GraphicsMagick `gm` (https://aheckmann.github.io/gm/)?

I want to do this on AWS lambda, so cant `write()` out to disk as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply specify the file extension you want to the `.write()` method and *gm* will convert it automatically in that format.

```
const gm = require('gm');

gm('sample.tiff')
  .write('out.jpeg', function (err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
});
```

If you need to output as [buffer](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm#buffers) instead of writing to disk, you can use `.toBuffer()` method:

```
gm('sample.tiff')
  .toBuffer('jpeg', function (err, buffer) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, can this be done with buffers? (I'm running this on an AWS lambda and can't write out to disk)

Comment: Yes you can also return the image as a buffer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's wrong but, with this library, it does not works for me. If I use:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp

it works for me. Maybe this helps someone.

```
const Jimp = require('jimp');

try {
  const readFile = await Jimp.read(filePath)
  await readFile.writeAsync(pathToConvertedFile)
  const buffPng = await fs.readFile(pathToConvertedFile);
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```